# Why do Dependency Injection frameworks support container hierarchies?

Tags: dependency-injection

I've been following [Daniel Cazzulino's](http://www.clariusconsulting.net/blogs/kzu/) series about [building a DI container using TDD](http://www.clariusconsulting.net/blogs/kzu/archive/2009/02/02/116399.aspx). In [part five of the series](http://www.viddler.com/explore/dcazzulino/videos/6/), he adds support for container hierarchies without commenting on what makes this feature useful. I've seen mention of support for hierarchies in many of the DI frameworks, but I'm having trouble understanding when they'd be used, and why. Can someone offer some insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a sample](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/06/21/Hierarchical-Containers.aspx) that uses child containers in a scenario similar to the one Matt describes. It uses child containers to select between different database configurations.

The key here is that most of the configuration is shared between the child containers (that shared part belongs in the parent container)

Answer (score 2):

I left a comment on kzu's blog asking the same question. It's a shame he didn't clarify the use-case for such a feature before coding it.

The only thing I could think of is if you wanted to have different types resolved from your container in different parts of your app. For example, if you had an order-entry system with two separate sections, and each section was identical except that they needed to present a different product list, you could create a child container for each section, and "override" the registration of your product repository in each. Whenever a section tried to resolve a product repository (or anything that depended on one) it would get the instance you set up in the child container rather than the parent. Sort of like overriding a virtual method.

This might be way off base, but it's the best I could come up with.

Answer (score 0):

There is good reason for having child containers if dependency injection is fully embraced by the project.  Let's imagine an application that has processes messages from two different, but similar systems.  Most of the processing is similar, but there are variations to support compatability from those systems.  Our aim is to re-use the code we can, while writing different code as requirements differ.

In OO programming, we wire together a series of classes that will collaborate to meet the system requirements.  The DI container takes this responsibility.  When a message arrives from a system, we want to build a set of collaborating classes suitable for processing a message from that particular system.

We have a top level container which has items that do not vary between the two systems.  Then, we have child containers that *do* vary between systems.  When a message arrives, we ask the approriate child DI container for a `messageProcessor`.  Based on the configuration of that container (falling back to the parent container as necessary) the DI framework can return a messageProcessor (being an object backed by approriate collaborators) for the system in question.

Please leave a comment if this is not a clear answer.  Also, you can search for "robot legs problem".  Each leg is identical but one needs a left foot and the other needs a right foot.  We could have a child DI container for each leg.

Answer (score 0):

The best example that I'm aware of for nested containers is a windowing system.  It's very nice for just separation of concerns to have each tab/window have it's own container independent of the other tabs/windows, with all window containers inheriting global dependencies from a parent container.

This is especially needed if you can have duplicate tab/windows, since in many cases you want to distinct instances of various classes for each duplicate tab/window